# Invalid argument: TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType) when closing Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, multiprocessing, typeerror

I'm implementing the IMPALA framework https://github.com/deepmind/scalable_agent which uses tensorflows multiprocessing. Everything seems to work fine as the experiment ran for the specified number of steps... however I start to get a type error when tensorflow is closing processes.

Does someone know what could've contributed to this error and how to solve it? This seems to be something with tensorflow rather than the original code itself.

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Closing all processes.
    [750.    450.     25.125]
    2020-01-13 17:01:00.624889: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1389] Invalid argument: TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 207, in __call__
        ret = func(*args)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/scalable_agent/py_process.py", line 86, in py_call
        result = self._out.recv()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
        buf = self._recv_bytes()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _recv_bytes
        return self._recv(size)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
        chunk = read(handle, remaining)

    TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)


    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 207, in __call__
        ret = func(*args)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/scalable_agent/py_process.py", line 86, in py_call
        result = self._out.recv()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
        buf = self._recv_bytes()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _recv_bytes
        return self._recv(size)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
        chunk = read(handle, remaining)

    TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)


         [[{{node scan/while/flow_environment_step/step}}]]
    INFO:tensorflow:All processes closed.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "experiment.py", line 689, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
        _sys.exit(main(argv))
      File "experiment.py", line 683, in main
        train(action_set, level_names)
      File "experiment.py", line 630, in train
        session.run(enqueue_ops)
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 788, in __exit__
        self._close_internal(exception_type)
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 826, in _close_internal
        self._sess.close()
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1082, in close
        self._sess.close()
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1244, in close
        ignore_live_threads=True)
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
        six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 696, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 257, in _run
        enqueue_callable()
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1257, in _single_operation_run
        self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)
      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
        run_metadata)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 207, in __call__
        ret = func(*args)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/scalable_agent/py_process.py", line 86, in py_call
        result = self._out.recv()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
        buf = self._recv_bytes()

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 411, in _recv_bytes
        return self._recv(size)

      File "/home/haianh/anaconda3/envs/lab/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
        chunk = read(handle, remaining)

    TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)


         [[{{node scan/while/flow_environment_step/step}}]]
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? If not can you provide some code to reproduce the error and debug?

Comment: Hi @nha011 , Could you try the same in Latest versions. Please share a  stand alone code  to reproduce the issue if you need further help .